# If condition not working in jinja in python flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I need to bifurcate the side navigation bar in html via values parsed in python to jinja via if conditions but is not helping,so here is the sample code

I have tried from various sites but i am not able to get pass through this problem

JINJA/HTML CODE:

```
{% if account == 'admin' %}
  <h1>ADMIN</h1>
{% else }
  <h1>USER</h1>
{% endif %}
```

PYTHON CODE:

```
@app.route('/loginscr/', methods =['POST'])
def loginscr():
    username = request.form['username'] 
    password = request.form['password'] 
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('Select * from auth_master where username = %s AND password = %s limit 1',(username,password))
    account = cursor.fetchone()
    print(username) 
    if account:
        print(account)
    return render_template('index.html', account = account)
```

Comment: but does it render `ADMIN` or `USER`  or you see nothing?

Comment: what gives you `print(account)` ? obviously not a single string, why don't you extract the name from the result row ? Maybe you just want to test the username ?

Comment: print(account) statement is used to fetch and check,whether admin is accessing or user is accessing.Take the print statement as for debugging purposes

Comment: `account = cursor.fetchone()` and  `if account == 'admin'`, you *want* to check what is inside account

Comment: Noted will make changes soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is syntax error in your else statement. It should be like this:

```
{% if account == 'admin' %} 
    <h1>ADMIN</h1> 
{% else %}
    <h1>USER</h1>
{% endif %}
```